# Why the run time of similar solution is so different?

Tags: c++, recursion, tree-balancing

There is a [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/balanced-binary-tree/) in LeetCode. I use a straightforward recursive solution to solve it, but the run time is to long, which is 170ms. Then I found a similar [solution](https://github.com/haoel/leetcode/blob/master/algorithms/balancedBinaryTree/balancedBinaryTree.cpp), which also is recursive, and the run time of this is just about 10ms. Why?

My solution:

```
class Solution
{
public:
    bool isBalanced(TreeNode* root)
    {
        if (root == nullptr)
            return true;

        bool left = isBalanced(root->left);
        bool right = isBalanced(root->right);

        bool curr = false;
        int sub = height(root->left) - height(root->right);
        if (sub < 2 && sub > -2)
            curr = true;

        return left && right && curr;
    }

private:
    int height(TreeNode* root)
    {
        if (root == nullptr)
            return 0;

        int leftHeight = height(root->left);
        int rightHeight = height(root->right);
        return (leftHeight > rightHeight) ? (leftHeight + 1) : (rightHeight + 1);
    }
};
```

The fast solution I found:

```
class Solution {
public:
    bool isBalanced(TreeNode *root) {
        if (root==NULL) return true;

        int left = treeDepth(root->left); 
        int right = treeDepth(root->right);

        if (left-right>1 || left-right < -1) {
            return false;
        }
        return isBalanced(root->left) && isBalanced(root->right);
    }

    int treeDepth(TreeNode *root) {
        if (root==NULL){
            return 0;
        }

        int left=1, right=1;

        left += treeDepth(root->left);
        right += treeDepth(root->right);

        return left>right?left:right;
    }

};
```

Thank you!

Comment: This might be a good time to experiment with learning how to use a profiler.

Comment: in the first solution, if we change something like below may be it will match    bool left = isBalanced(root->left);
 if(!left){
  return false;
 }
    bool right = isBalanced(root->right);
    if(!right){
     return false;
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution calls both `isBalanced` and `height`, *always*. For every single node in the tree.

The faster solution calls `treeDepth` for every single node, but bails out early and doesn't call `isBalanced` if it knows the tree is not balanced. It's an optimization to not call unnecessary (recursive/expensive) functions.

Comment: The result of profiler is same as what you mentioned. Thank you!